# If I were you, If the weather were etc

Tags: grammar

[image: If i were you, If the weather were etc.]

I thought we can only use "were" with "you, they, we". What's happening?

If you can't see the picture, You should know there is a picture with these statements at the top of the post.

If (I) was/were

You can say: if l/he/she/it was or
if I/he/she/it were

I wouldn't go out if I were you

It's not a very nice place. I wouldn't go there If I were you. (Or..If l was you)

It would be nice if the weather was better.
(or .. If the weather were better)

Comment: It's a subjunctive form of the verb **to be**:  I were, you were, he/she/it were, we were, you were, they were.  It is the same for all persons. It doesn't get conjugated.  We can use the subjunctive for various reasons in English -[more info here](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subjunctive_mood.htm#:~:text=Verb%20Changes%20with%20the%20Subjunctive%20Mood%20%20,%20%20I%20propose%20she%20make%20sushi.%20)

Comment: @BillyKerr  It's not a subjunctive. Nowadays we tend to call it **Irrealis** _were_, a more formal alternative to "was".

Comment: @BillyKerr I'm inclined to agree with you, but it seems far more complicated than that. I you look up irrealis (a word,like you, I've never never heard of till today) in  and Wikipedia you get https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood which lists 22 different irrealist moods, including subjunctive. But I would suggest that this is far too complicated for ELL and would only confuse learners. Such distinctions and arguments belong over on SE Linguistics.

Comment: @KavehBehnia The "were" that you are referring to, i.e. the "were" that is used to express modal remoteness, is unique to the verb "be" and is limited to 1st and 3rd person singular.

Comment: @KavehBehnia Please [edit] your question and type out the relevant words from the image. People who use [screen readers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader) cannot see the text in images. Further, people who search for terms in the image text won't find it. Also, it means people cannot copy-paste those portions of your question.

Comment: I have a better idea why not typing the statements in picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a special case.

In conditional expressions with "if" you can use "was" *or* "were" with singular pronouns. This is because the condition is "unreal".   When we say "It would be nice if the weather were better."  The statement "The weather were better" is unreal.  Really, the weather is bad.

Using "were" is considered more formal.  It is a piece of grammar from older English that is becoming less common in modern English.
It is also common in idioms like "If I were you"

Don't worry because you can also use "was" as usual.

Comment: If I were rich used to be standard. Nowadays people say If I was rich interchangeably with it.  But I would not call it a special case.

Comment: It is a special case, because in almost all case "he were...." is  a mistake.

Comment: I don't think that is a valid argument, really.

Comment: The answer box is right there, if you think you can write a better answer.

Comment: It is a traditional conditional, not a special case.